# FlareSolverr in docker

Tags: python, docker

I have flaresolver installed in docker.

When I try to request from postman - the response is correct, but from the python script I get a 500 error.

```
def get_parsed_page(url, delay=0.5):
data = {
    "cmd": "request.get",
    "url": url,
    "maxTimeout": 60000
}
headers = { 
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
time.sleep(delay)
print(requests.post("http://localhost:8191/v1", data=data, headers=headers))
return BeautifulSoup(requests.post("http://localhost:8191/v1", data=data, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
```

[image]

Comment: have you checked the logs of your python script ? Error 500 mean something is wrong on the backend / python script side.

Comment: @micheal-choudhary can you tell me where i can see the logs?

Comment: try to do ```docker logs $container_name``` replace $container_name with the name of your container name. you should see the logs, if your application is printing the logs.

Comment: i think, you are missing some header in the request done by postman. you should copy the curl command from the browser F12 window and import it into the postman. it should work because it will be 1:1 request sent by your browser. Here is an article about it: https://medium.com/@tiboprea/how-to-replicate-requests-from-the-chrome-network-tab-into-postman-4ec6016ee18c

Comment: @MichealChoudhary adding headers didn't help. In the logs, I see the same thing as in the console - information about the 500 error

Comment: i would suggest you to find a way to get the logs out the apps.
This problem has nothing to do with docker container

Answer (score 0):

In your request, change the `data=data` part to `json=data`. Final code should look like this:

```py
def get_parsed_page(url, delay=0.5):
    data = {
        "cmd": "request.get",
        "url": url,
        "maxTimeout": 60000
    }
    headers = { 
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(requests.post("http://localhost:8191/v1", json=data, headers=headers))
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.post("http://localhost:8191/v1", json=data, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
```

Ah, and i recently made a [FlareSolverr wrapper](https://github.com/NandeMD/FSPy) for some of my personal projects. You can download from pip: `pip install fspy`.

And the code will be a little bit cleaner with [fspy](https://github.com/NandeMD/FSPy).

```py
from fspy import FlareSolverr
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


solver = FlareSolverr()


def get_parsed_page():
    url = "someurl"
    data = solver.request_get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(data.solution.response, "lxml")
```

**Note: You should have a running FlareSolverr instance/image for fspy to work, or else you will get an error.**